# Can't add new user in Windows 10 Settings because dialog closes

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, dialog

I can't add new user accounts in Settings, because the dialog closes:

[image]

Attempting to convert my local account to a Microsoft one doesn't work neither (and I don't care). So it seems some problem related with account dialogs.

I can create another user via `control userpasswords2`, but I would prefer that the Settings way worked too.

If I create another user, there the account dialogs work. So the problem is only in my account. But I don't want to remove my account and use another one.

Is there any way to repair these dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was

1. Go to `%LocalAppData%\Packages`
2. Rename `Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy` to `Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy.backup` (you can remove it at the end).
3. Open Windows PowerShell as admin
4. Enter this command:

   ```
   Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Restore Point and then try this:

Start `PowerShell.exe`, copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> the following command, paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> it in PowerShell window, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.AccountsControl | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I also tried removing `%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.AccountsControl_cw5n1h2txyewy` before reinstall.

Comment: Has the folder been recreated automatically after running the command?

Comment: Yes, it has been recreated.

Comment: If you're comfortable running a [ProcMon trace](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/process-monitor-track-events-generate-log-file/), you may be able to find out why the dialog closes...whether it's due to file/registry access permissions etc.

Comment: Thanks! Following that tutorial I found out it was CloudExperienceHost.

Comment: Nice! Fixed it?

Comment: Yes, removing the package files and reinstalling it fixed the problem