# Can't add new Microsoft account because dialog closes

Tags: windows-11, user-accounts

I can't add a new Microsoft Account because the dialog closes... I tried everything here : [Can't add new user in Windows 10 Settings because dialog closes](https://superuser.com/questions/1113853/cant-add-new-user-in-windows-10-settings-because-dialog-closes)
but the problem is not solved.
https://imgur.com/a/rMXGFYF

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: If the initial repairs Harry has suggested do not resolve the issues, try a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link

Comment: I've solved this problem by adding a new admin with cmd and then I can use it to add another Microsoft account.